# Perl : How to sort value and put them into array

Tags: perl

I'm very new to Perl but here's what I'm trying to do for example the variable has a value of apple,banana,cat,dog, I need to put this value into individual array like for example

```
my $value = "apple","banana","cat","dog";
```

Result:

```
my @A = "apple";
my @B = "banana";
my @c = "cat";
my @D = "dog";
```

just like that? I hope someone help me on this one , thank you very much

Comment: Why are you using 4 separate arrays?

Comment: because I need it to be arranged in alphabetical order using array as a holder for those value. so if the script capture this letter it will go to that array , for example if the script has the value of yoyo it will go to array @Y. just like that , I hope you understand what I mean. thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> because I need it to be arranged in alphabetical order using array as
> a holder for those value. so if the script capture this letter it will
> go to that array , for example if the script has the value of yoyo it
> will go to array @Y. just like that , I hope you understand what I
> mean. thank you

It looks like what you want to do is create a multi-level data structure, so you can report something like this.

```
A: apple, astronaut
B: banana, buttons
C: cat, carnage
D: dog
P: perl
Y: yoyo, yawn
```

Now you would not typically use 26 different arrays for that. That's really bad style, and also incredibly hard to maintain, as you can't make it dynamic.

Instead, you would use a multi-level data structure. A hash reference is great for that.

```perl
$sorted_words_by_first_letter = {
  'a' => [ 'apple', 'astronaut' ],
  'b' => [ 'banana', 'buttons' ],
   # ...
}
```

You would have to iterate the list, look at the first letter of each word, and put them into the right key inside your hash reference.

```perl
my $sorted_words_by_first_letter;
my @words = qw/ banana apple astronaut yoyo buttons /;
foreach my $word (@words) {
  
  # find the first character
  $word =~ m/^(.)/; 
  
  # put it at the end of the array for the appropriate letter
  push @{ $sorted_words_by_first_letter->{$1} }, $word;
}
```

You can read more about references and multi-level data structures in Perl at [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref) and [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut). You can read more about regular expressions at [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre).

If your input is not a list, but a string, you [need to `split`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) it first.

```perl
my @words = split /,/, "banana,apple,astronaut,yoyo,buttons";
```

To turn that back into the output I showed above, you need to iterate the keys.

```perl
foreach my $letter ( sort keys %{ $sorted_words_by_first_letter } ) {
  printf "%s: %s\n", uc($letter),
    join ', ', sort @{ $sorted_words_by_first_letter->{$letter };
}
```

That'll output the following:

```
A: apple, astronaut
B: banana, buttons
Y: yoyo
```

---

To show you why you shouldn't use specific variables for each different letter, consider this code. I'm only showing this so you see why it is a bad idea. Please don't do this.

```perl
my ( @A, @B, @C, @D, @E, @F, @G, @H, @I, @J, @K, @L, @M, 
     @N, @O, @P, @Q, @R, @S, @T, @U, @V, @W, @X, @Y, @Z );

my @words = qw/ banana apple astronaut yoyo buttons /;
foreach my $word (@words) {

  # find the first character, assign to var
  ( my $letter ) = $word =~ m/^(.)/; 

  if ($letter =~ m/a/i) {
    push @A, $word;
  } elsif ($letter =~ m/b/i) {
    push @B, $word;
  } elsif ($letter =~ m/c/i) {
    push @C, $word;
  } # ...
```

As you can see, this gets very long and unwieldy very quickly, and we haven't even talked about how to use it afterwards. That would require the same amount of repetition again. So please don't do this.
All it does is make your code really hard to maintain.

Comment: Oh , The last answer that you put is the one that I'm looking for. I hope I could explain it to you better why I needed it to have individual array per letter. Its Interesting if you could see my script. Thank you for this. I'm doing a web scrapping using perl. and alot of value that I need to sort and put into individual array per letter to be arranged.

Comment: @johndenverabella I'm happy to look at your code. Post it on [codereview.se] and shoot me a link!

Comment: its very long script , I hope I could show it to you via call if you are interested but only if youre available. it is too much to ask hahaha but last answer I think I could use that one. Thank you very much

Comment: It might be worth showing how to iterate over the keys in the dynamic hash.  eg `foreach my $k( keys %$sorted_words_by_first_letter ){`.

Comment: @simbabque for the last answer that you posted only the letter push into array @A , how can I include all or complete word on that array ? @A = apple

Comment: @johndenverabella replace `$letter` with `$word`. Sorry, I didn't run the code, just wrote it down here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding some concepts.

Variables that start with a dollar sign `$` can only hold a single value. They are called *scalars*, and they cannot be arrays.

```perl
my $value = "apple","banana","cat","dog";
```

The value of `$value` will be just be `"apple"`. The other parts of that list will be discarded.

Your variables `@A`, `@B`, `@C` and `@D` are all arrays. When a variable has an at `@` as its sigil, it's an array.

```perl
my @A = "apple";
my @B = "banana";
my @c = "cat";
my @D = "dog";
```

This code indeed creates four arrays with one value each, which is fine. But it's probably not what you were asked to do.

I think what you meant to do was assign the list of words into an array, and then assign each element of the array to an individual scalar variable.

```perl
# make an array of words
my @words = ( "apple","banana","cat","dog" );

# assign each one to a single variable.
my ($apple, $banana, $cat, $dog) = @words;
```

The above code uses list assignment with a list of variables on the left hand side of the equals `=` to put the elements of the array into those variables.

Another way of doing this is to assign each one individually by accessing elements in the array. To do this, the sigil changes from an `@` to a `$`.

```perl
my $apple  = $words[0];
my $banana = $words[1];
my $cat    = $words[2];
my $dog    = $words[3];
```

None of this has anything to do with sorting, though.

If you want to sort the array, you'd use the [`sort` built-in](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort). Your list is already sorted alphabetically, so this is not very exciting.

```perl
my @sorted = sort @values;
print "@sorted"; # apple banana cat dog
```

Comment: I'm leaving my original answer, although I think it's not what OP wants.

Comment: I do have a question, my @words has a value of apple , banana, dog ,cat how can I separate this value and push it to individual array ? like the apple will go to my @A and banana will go to my @B ? In that way I will have its own array per letter. Thats what I'm trying to do

Comment: @johndenverabella so I think you made a mistake in the code in your question. William's answer shows you how to split a string. But he's just deleted it.

Comment: @johndenverabella see my other answer as well please. You really sholdn't have an `@Y` in your code. You'd have to do some really weird coding to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you very much for youre answer, I really get the point . I hope I can show you my script rightnow but I don't know if its possible, I'm new to Perl but I'm doing really complex work right now. Thank you very much I will try to study the one that you explain.